# How can i show tooltip error with TextInput in react native

Tags: validation, react-native, textinput

[image]

I want to build a text input like above image with react native

```
    <TextInput
          placeholder = "Enter Your mobile number"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tooltip library. Show the tooltip on validation failed.

```
npm install react-native-tooltip --save
```

OR

```
npm install react-native-popover-tooltip --save
```

Comment: it's help me lot but how can i show black popup with pin

Comment: @devedv You still don't provide an example in the answer. As msparer stated your answer could become invalid if the package changes ^^

Answer (score 0):

TextInput do not support this as a prop, what i am suggesting is a what i am using as a workaround after investing tons of time into it.
Even Instagram app do not have is functionality,
you can use alert dialog or popover for this.

Lib metioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861880/6797088 is a good way to popovers.